# How to trigger an event based on the window.scrollY value in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, use-state

I have a button that I want to be able to animate for whenever people are viewing my page on their mobile devices. At first the way I had it set up seemed to work but it was not consistent with other browsers (Safari specifically).

The idea is that when someone is scrolling through my page, I want this button to animate its border color upon arriving a certain scrollY value depending on their device's viewport such as the height and width. The code I have so far is as follows:

React Code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Button() {
  const [isActive, setActiveButton] = useState(false);

  function handleScroll() {
    const deviceScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
    const deviceScreenHeight = window.screen.height;

    if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight <= 900 && window.scrollY >= 1020) {
      setActiveButton(true);
    } else {
      setActiveButton(false);
    }

    console.log(window.scrollY);
  }

  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  return (
    <div className="main-container">
      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>

        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic, saepe,
          ratione nemo possimus odio fugiat quasi asperiores numquam enim
          consectetur obcaecati animi quas debitis, tenetur quos optio dolorum
          doloremque? Fuga.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div className={`${isActive ? "button-container button-container--active" : "button-container"}`}>
        <a className="button" href="www.google.com">
          Button
        </a>
      </div>

      <div>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae
          debitis fugit, id voluptate aut praesentium, vitae, at autem eum
          inventore saepe illum sit cumque expedita exercitationem. Inventore
          iste atque architecto.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Button;
```

CSS Code

```
.button-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid rgba(25, 211, 218, 0);
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.button-container--active {
  transition: background-color 0.1s ease-in-out, border 0.2s ease-in-out;
  animation: glow 2s infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes glow {
  50% {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.18);
    border: 2px solid rgba(25, 211, 218, 0.5);
  }
}
```

Basically, the div containing the button should have the ".button-container" class by default but then the class ".button-container--active" should be added once the user crosses the scrollY value set in order to initiate the animation.

At first this seemed to work but then it started to get complicated down the line depending on the user's device viewport and I ended up with a long function essentially looking like this:

```
function addAnimation() {
        const deviceScreenWidth = window.screen.width;
        const deviceScreenHeight = window.screen.height;

        if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight <= 670 && window.scrollY >= 2887) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight > 671 && deviceScreenHeight <= 736 && window.scrollY >= 3065) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight > 737 && deviceScreenHeight <= 813 && window.scrollY >= 3322) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight > 814 && deviceScreenHeight <= 897 && window.scrollY >= 3480) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight > 898 && deviceScreenHeight <= 930 && window.scrollY >= 3530) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else if (deviceScreenWidth <= 835 && deviceScreenHeight > 930 && deviceScreenHeight <= 960 && window.scrollY >= 3490) {
            setActiveButton(true);
        } else {
            setActiveButton(false);
        }
    }
```

Is there a simpler way to accomplish this goal where I can have this button to animate no matter the user's viewport height/width settings? I just want to be able to have it animate for mobile users as I have a separate functionality working for desktop users.

I apologize if my code is looking pretty ugly I'm still trying to get the hang of React.

Comment: You will never be able to accommodate all viewports this way. Using IntersectionObserver instead of all that device specific testing should make things easier - and responsive whatever the viewport.

Comment: @AHaworth you were absolutely correct. I did my research on the IntersectionObserver, implemented it onto my project, and it worked perfectly. If you'd like to place it as an answer I'll mark this as solved! Thank you, again!